# Should you use quotes on system identifiers in your query?

Tags: sql

It may depend on the database type, but is there a preference (by the database and not the coder) or is it better to use quotes? Is it:

- Faster?
- Less error prone?
- Helps prevent injection (if using a PDO or not)?

Assume there is nothing requiring the use (spaces, reserved words, etc.).

MySQL:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = '$name';
```

ANSI:

```
SELECT "id" FROM "table" WHERE "name" = '$name';
```

vs:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = $name;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/84162) talks about the requirement to use quotes in MySQL, but I'm interested in when it's not required by the db, but it might be preferred/better for the aspects (and perhaps more) that I listed above.

Comment: We started using them because it seemed cleaner as you can use any ifentifier without the risk of hitting a keyword, but then we stopped again because it made the queries much less readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes around identifiers are used only during the query parsing stage - a stage that goes through the SQL statement, and figures out its syntactic elements. Compared to other stages (query optimization, query execution, and passing the results back to the caller) the parsing stage is relatively short. Therefore, you should not expect any measurable speedup or slowdown from using quotes around your identifiers, regardless of your particular RDBMS.

As far as being more or less error prone goes, missing quotes around multipart identifiers become apparent very quickly during the development stage, so the practice of placing quotes everywhere it is not worth the trouble, because the readability to humans suffers significantly.

Finally, adding quotes around identifiers would not help you prevent injection attacks; same goes for *not* placing quotes around all identifiers. Many SQL script generators take this route to avoid `if` statements all over the script testing if the identifier is multipart or not.

The only situation where quoting all identifiers is a good idea is when you generate SQL programmatically, and the results are *not* intended for human readers.

Comment: *...when you generate SQL programmatically, and the results are not intended for human readers* and yet practically all SQL generators use quoted identifiers <sigh>

Answer (score 3):

I am not a fan of using quoted identifiers.  They take too long to type and they clutter the code, making it harder for humans to read.

Also, I prefer to discourage the use of reserved words as identifiers in SQL.  To me, this is just good practice.  I mean, who wants to read something like:

```
select `select`, `from` as `as`
from <some really messed up table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the the bottome version because I find it easier to read but it depends on the way you echoed your query. There is no difference in the performance as it reads past the quotes unless it is need so you really don't know it unless writing a WHERE clause in your query that contains more than one variable.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it's faster NOT to use quotes for numeric identifiers; why add the potential overhead of a data type conversion to a query you want (presumably) to be as performant as possible?

Comment: The OP is referring to column/table identifiers, not to quoted string or number literals.